# update table with c# and mysql

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

i apologize in advance for the elementary questions

i am using:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from some_table;"
```

to retrieve data

can i do use the same thing to update data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that command is an instance of SqlCommand.  In which case, yes you can.  Here is a code fragment detailing what you should do to update data:

```
command.Connection = (Insert connection string here);
command.CommandText = (Insert update statement);
int numRowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As I type three answers came in.  No need to apologize; we're happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are [some simple examples on reading and writing to a database](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp).

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways, but one is to use a SQL update statement and [parameterized statements](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The above examples are great ones, you could also look at LINQ.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398.aspx